# Keep getting "error: expected identifier or '(' " but i don't see why

Tags: compiler-errors

Every time I compile, I keep seeing this message. Am I missing something? I've checked it over a few times and it seems to be correct. The line in particular mentioned in the error is after the main function had been declared.

```
// Caesar Cipher Program

int main(int argc, string argv[]); //need to check that argv[1] is not a float
{
    for (argc == 2 && int key = atoi(argv[1]) && key > 0) // Check that argv[0] is the file name as well? converts "key" (string) into int value
    {
        string text = get_string("plaintext: ");// Prompts user for plaintext

        printf("ciphertext: ");// Prints ciphertext

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)// Example of good design bc doesn't have to check the length of the string on every iteration
            {
                if (isalpha(text[i]) == true && isupper(text[i]) == true)
                    {
                        int j = 'text[i]' % 65;
                        int k = (j + key) % 26;
                        printf('65 + k');
                    }
                else if (isalpha(text[i]) == true && islower(text[i]) == true)
                    {
                        int l = 'text[i]' % 97;
                        int m = (l + key) % 26;
                        printf('97 + m');
                    }
                else
                    printf(text[i]);
            }

        return 1;
    }

    default
    printf("Try again.");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Write the language please

Comment: Hint: `int main(int argc, string argv[]); ` Why the `;` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found your error If you look you end the main function at the top with a semicolon should not be: 
`int main(int argc, string argv[])`**;**`//need to check that argv[1] is not a float` But rather:
`int main(int argc, string argv[]) //need to check that argv[1] is not a float` If you see you have an extra semicolon. Hope this helps please tell me if it does.